# Cumulative Distribution Plot Interpretation

Tags: distributions, self-study, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

I have data for a cumulative distribution plot. I dont have the function. Based on this data alone, I need to interpret the probability density function and describe the probability distribution. How do I approach this? Should I be studying sigmoid curve functions and inflection points in order to find a function that fits the cdf plot then take the derivative and find the probability density function? How do I compare different distributions to judge which ones best fits my cdf data? I dont have a math background and hoping to figure out a study plan to attack problems like this.

Comment: The first two sentences sound like some of the topics covered in a first semester differential Calculus course.  Knowing that material would serve you well.

Comment: Why do you need this? It does not seem likely that this need arose spontaneously as one would usually have the original data to create a cumulative plot. Is this for a course? If so, the `self-study` tag would be required to follow the site rules, and answers should be limited to hints alone. Please respond.

Comment: OK, what kind of data? Is this from a random variable or points from a smooth function?

Comment: The answer depends on whether this is discrete random data, i.e., with noise, or deterministic; without noise.

Comment: It is yields, returns on an investments, so it has increments but they are very small: 0.000001%. Its smooth so I would say a continuous random variable.